# Obter a estrutura de uma tabela através de uma consulta

Tags: mysql

Através do PHPMyAdmin, acedendo a uma tabela, podemos ver a estrutura da mesma no separador `structure` que nos lista os campos, os tipos de dados que cada um aceita, entre outras informações.

[image: Captura de Tela]

Como posso obter através de uma consulta os detalhes de determinada tabela na base de dados, mais especificamente a estrutura da mesma, os seus campos e o tipo de dados que cada campo aceita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essas informações pode ser obtidas através do [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html)

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'nome_da_tabela'
```

forma abrevida:

```
describe nome_da_tabela
```

Answer (score 2):

## Faça assim:

```
DESCRIBE tabela;
```

Ou assim:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tabela;
```

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi é `DESCRIBE nome_da_tabela`

ref.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html